# Webhook to Wix Not Creating Log

Tags: webhooks, velo

I have created a webhook in Wix to connect to an assessment result in the Assessment Generator website. I put the URL in the required place on the Assessment Generator website, but when I finish an assessment, no information is coming back to Wix (I checked the log, there is nothing coming in). Can someone tell me where in my code I am going wrong? I have made sure to publish my changes, so I know that's not the issue.

[image: I entered the URL here in Assessment Generator]

```
import {ok} from 'wix-http-functions';
import wixData from 'wix-data';

export async function post_AssessGen(request) {
  console.log(request);
  const body = await request.body.json();
  console.log(body);

const myCollection = "CollectionResultsDetail"
let toInsert = {
  "Email":        body.Email,
  "Worship":   body.Type1,
  "Ministry":    body.Type4
};

wixData.insert("myCollection", toInsert)
  .then((item) => {
console.log(item); //see item below
    })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  return ok();
}
```